# Merging pandas dataframes on potentially different join keys

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe A with columns like so:

| ACCOUNT_NAME | SFDC_ACCOUNT_NAME | COMPANY_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acme Inc | Acme, Inc. | Acme |
| Donut Heaven | None | Doughnut Heaven |
| Super Foods | Sooper Foods | None |

I want to merge on additional columns but I am not sure if this additional data was captured using `ACCOUNT_NAME`, `SFDC_ACCOUNT_NAME`, or `COMPANY_NAME`. This data looks like the table below. There is a join key column that could represent either `ACCOUNT_NAME`, `SFDC_ACCOUNT_NAME`, or `COMPANY_NAME`.

| CAPTURED_COMPANY_NAME | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acme Inc | 2 | 3 |
| Sooper Foods | 6 | 7 |
| Doughnut Heaven | 5 | 8 |

I want the final table to look like this:

| ACCOUNT_NAME | SFDC_ACCOUNT_NAME | COMPANY_NAME | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Acme Inc | Acme, Inc. | Acme | 2 | 3 |
| Donut Heaven | None | Doughnut Heaven | 5 | 8 |
| Super Foods | Sooper Foods | None | 6 | 7 |

I could merge this second dataset onto the first three times (one for each join key) but then of course columns `value1` and `value2` would be repeated three times. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of join are you using?

Comment: I am doing a left join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
# df

   ACCOUNT_NAME SFDC_ACCOUNT_NAME     COMPANY_NAME
0      Acme Inc        Acme, Inc.             Acme
1  Donut Heaven               NaN  Doughnut Heaven
2   Super Foods      Sooper Foods              NaN

# df1

  CAPTURED_COMPANY_NAME  value1  value2
0              Acme Inc       2       3
1          Sooper Foods       6       7
2       Doughnut Heaven       5       8
```

Doing:

```
# Merge each individually, and concat the results:
out = pd.concat([df.merge(df1, left_on=x, right_on='CAPTURED_COMPANY_NAME') for x in df.columns], ignore_index=True)
# Left Merge:
# out = df.merge(pd.concat([df.merge(df1, left_on=x, right_on='CAPTURED_COMPANY_NAME') for x in df.columns], ignore_index=True), how='left')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   ACCOUNT_NAME SFDC_ACCOUNT_NAME     COMPANY_NAME CAPTURED_COMPANY_NAME  value1  value2
0      Acme Inc        Acme, Inc.             Acme              Acme Inc       2       3
1   Super Foods      Sooper Foods              NaN          Sooper Foods       6       7
2  Donut Heaven               NaN  Doughnut Heaven       Doughnut Heaven       5       8
```

Comment: My apologies, I needed to edit the original question. There are only two dataframes but with a join key that could represent the value in one of those three columns.

Comment: @mdrishan Updated~

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Unfortunately I believe that this approach leaves any unmatched rows from each merge and those rows are then duplicated multiple times in the final dataset. I cannot just drop any null rows because there are rows in df with no corresponding match in df1 across any of the potential join keys.

Comment: No... this is doing three inner joins, which will not leave any unmatched rows. You can add back the unmatched rows using the "Left Merge" approach I have commented out.

Comment: You are completely right and I completely missed that commented out line. I wish I could attach a facepalm emoji to a SO comment. Thank you for your help!!!